# Decorator class which checks if passed instance variable is not None

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators

I have an issue where I'm trying to create a simple Class decorator which checks for passed variables presence (that is they're not None). Problem is, this is done inside another class, so the checked variables are from `self.`. Basically I'm trying to create a wrapper which iterates over given self variables and checks if they're not None.

```py
class CheckForVariablesPresence:
  """Wrapper for checking if given variable(s) are not None.
  """

  def __init__(self, *variables):
    self.variables = variables

  def __call__(self, func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      for variable in self.variables:
        if variable is None:
          raise KeyError(
            "Variable not found.\n",
            "Run the appropriate method first.",
          )

   return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The thing is, I can't pass `self.variable` in the method's decorator, as self isn't even yet created.

```py
@CheckForVariablesPresence(self.variable)
def __repr__(self):
  return str(self.variable)
```

Any ideas how I could do this differently (and better)? I started with one function for checking the exact variable, but the variables checked are growing and depend on each and different method I'm calling, thus the reason I wanted to use a wrapper which could iterate over them.

Comment: Rather than constantly checking if `variable` is not `None`, make it a property which makes sure it never *becomes* `None`.

Comment: Can't do, the user has to first call a method which will create the variable. Until then, I don't want him to use another method that relies on that first method to be activated beforehand.

Comment: Sounds like poor class design; I stand by my original recommendation.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Although I can't reimplement everything (due to how the class is used in another module) I just fell back to just trying to catch the `AttributeError` if the attribute wasn't initialised by the proper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self answer**: This idea of doing this in that way is quite bad - as pointed out by @chepner in the comments. Although I think he meant doing something else, I resolved it in another way (due to limitations of how it had to work because of another module). Basically the `__getattr__` method is what I was looking for and I've implemented a custom `AttributeError` message for when the attribute that's available, but not yet initialised, was called.

This is a sample.

```py
def __getattr__(self, name: str):
    value = self.__dict__.get(name)
    if value is None and name in self.__available_attributes:
        raise AttributeError(
            f"Attribute {name} not found. Run the appropriate method first or set it."
        )
    elif value is None:
        raise AttributeError(f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{name} is invalid")

    return value
```